# How to add gesture detector to a ViewPager

Tags: android, gesture, android-pageradapter

**What I want to do:**

Image will be slidable  by viewpager but people can zoomIn or zoomOut by gesture detector.

**Problem:**

I can slide image using viewpager but don't know to how to add gesture detector in my Viewpager.

**Code:**

Activity:

```
    public class ImageSlider extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdpater customSwipeAdpater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_slider);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        customSwipeAdpater = new CustomSwipeAdpater(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customSwipeAdpater);
    }
}
```

PagerAdpater:

```
    public class CustomSwipeAdpater extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.wall,R.drawable.welcome};
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public CustomSwipeAdpater(Context context){
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == (RelativeLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View item_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout. swipe_layout,container,false);
        imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.ivSliderImage);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.tvSliderImageText);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        textView.setText("Image:" + position);
        container.addView(item_view);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

**How to add gesture Detector in this code?**

Comment: did you see source code of PhotoView ? it does the same. It's from googler Chirsbanes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Photoview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample) library do exact things you want it's Also support rotating.
create touchAttacher and pass your image to it and it's Done.

Here is part of **PhotoViewAttacher** code which does exactly what you want :

```
public PhotoViewAttacher(ImageView imageView, boolean zoomable) {
    mImageView = new WeakReference<>(imageView);

    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    ViewTreeObserver observer = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (null != observer)
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    // Make sure we using MATRIX Scale Type
    setImageViewScaleTypeMatrix(imageView);

    if (imageView.isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }
    // Create Gesture Detectors...
    mScaleDragDetector = VersionedGestureDetector.newInstance(
            imageView.getContext(), this);

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(imageView.getContext(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                // forward long click listener
                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    if (null != mLongClickListener) {
                        mLongClickListener.onLongClick(getImageView());
                    }
                }
            });

    mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new DefaultOnDoubleTapListener(this));

    // Finally, update the UI so that we're zoomable
    setZoomable(zoomable);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't able to implement the library sample code in my code. will you help me to do that?

Comment: @yeahia2508 I do the same thing you want couple of month ago. if you see sample in repository it has activity **ViewPagerActivity** I think it's solve your problem.

Comment: It's so easy and clean. if you have problem let me know I'll glad to help you :)

Comment: Please Help me. Thank you very much.. just add the required code with my code. that's it..

Comment: I already added photoview library in my project.. but don't know how to use it.

Comment: Did you see **ViewPagerActivity** in sample ?

Comment: yeah but can't find hackyviewpager :(

Comment: Here is link of hackyViewPager https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/HackyViewPager.java

Comment: Thank you very much it's now working.. please change your answer so that other people can get benefit from your answer. ask them to add photoview view in res and add it in pageradpter. Also remaind them to implement HackyViewPager. thank you agian..

Comment: Another issu brother. image scale are cached. how to retrore it when view pager go to another image?

Comment: what do mean by cached ? when go to another page it's return to default state

Comment: @yeahia2508 as I see sample apk it's returns to default size; double check it ;)