# Zoom/dezoom image during Crop in Android

Tags: android, crop, zooming

I'm using the following code crop the captured image. My question is that 
1) How can i get the output which high quality (resolution shouldn't look awkward) 
2) How can a user can zoom-in OR zoom-out the image. In current state user can zoom-in but can zoom-out from a limit where image fills the screen.
Kindly suggest any solution.
Thanks

Code:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

Comment: for **ZoomIn** & **ZoomOut** see my answer at following link it may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839199/how-to-add-gesture-detector-to-a-viewpager/34839566#34839566

Comment: for first part of your question I didnt get what you mean ? if your image be high quality then your cropped imaged will be high quality

Comment: @Amir Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right but i want to resize the image in good quality if it is of low quality after crop.

Comment: I think you should use some image processing algorithm to achieve this. like **Median Filtering** or similar things

Comment: @Amir your link is about zoomig the image insisde the app (i.e. image is used in imageView) but in my case implicit intent is used to crop, and i can't this library in that case.